# Function that will cache the values of a sequence

Tags: .net, f#

How to defined a function that will cache the values of a sequence and print "Cached" to standard output every time the value requested from the sequence is actually cached.

`let cacheObserver (input:seq<'a>) : seq<'a> =o failwith "cacheObserver not yet implemented!"`

Can someone explain how this can be done? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out how this is done in the [F# BCL's implementation of Seq.cache](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/687d2118488e84317c9965ac93ea454069a51618/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L971). Line 997 is where you'd print that you're caching a new element.

Basically, you need a mutable backing field to store the values you read from the original sequence. Then, each time a request for a new element comes in, you first check to see if you already have that element in the mutable backing field. If not, you advance the original and add the new elements to the backing field.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for suggestion, maybe any example ? :)

Comment: The link I gave you already contains a full implementation.